# Value of Heisenberg exchange constant

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, protons, exchange-interaction

I am aware that for two interacting electrons, the portion of the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_{\text{ex}}$ is equal to$$J\begin{pmatrix}\frac14&0&0&0\\0&-\frac14&\frac12&0\\0&\frac12&-\frac14&0\\0&0&0&\frac14\end{pmatrix},$$where $J$ is the value of the Heisenberg exchange interaction. However, despite a lot of Internet searching, I have been unable to find what the value of this interaction actually is. So what is the value of $J$ for two electrons separated by a distance $r$? Or an electron and a proton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would get electrons separated by a fixed distance $r$ in quantum mechanics. Even in a Hydrogen atom, the electron to proton distance is just an average computed for a given orbital. But you can think of Heisenberg's $J(S_1 \cdot S_2)$ term as the leading Taylor approximation to a potentially more complicated interaction and therefore solve for $J$ after the fact by comparing energies.

Consider two electrons with negligible Coulomb interaction confined by some harmonic potential. This means the first two energy eigenvalues will be
\begin{equation}
E_0 = \hbar \omega / 2, \quad E_1 = 3 \hbar \omega / 2.
\end{equation}
If the electron spins are anti-aligned, we can get away with putting them in the same ground state wavefunction and therefore find a total energy of $E_{+-} = \hbar \omega$. With aligned spins, however, we need one of each wavefunction in order to anti-symmetrize them. Hence, $E_{++} = 2\hbar \omega$. This is now enough to reason out an effective Hamiltonian which treats the spin and ignores position information. We simply write
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{1}{2} \hbar\omega \left (3 + S_1 \cdot S_2 \right )
\end{equation}
since this gives the right $E_{++}$ and $E_{+-}$. In other words, this toy model has $J = \hbar \omega / 2$. It is now possible to gradually make the setup more complicated by including spin-orbit interaction, non-equally spaced energy levels, etc.

Comment: I am not sure about fixing the distance between electrons, either, but nature does it for us for nuclei. The idea of chemical structure determination with nuclear magnetic resonance does make use of the fact that the relative positions of the nuclear spins are fixed with fairly good accuracy in molecules. I don't think that changes the spin coupling though. It modulates the strength, which leads to different spectra depending on molecular configuration.

Comment: You don't think that changes the spin coupling compared to what? Other materials?

Comment: Yes, the strength of the spin coupling does change with distance, but the general structure of how spins couple does not because that is, at the end of the day, about an (energy) eigenvalue spectrum. At most we could say that orbital angular momentum falls out of the equation if two spins are at a fixed distance, and we only have to deal with spin-spin coupling, I guess. My only point was that we have both kinds of systems. Electrons are always "in motion" (at least in chemical scenarios I believe) but the nuclei are almost "fixed".